# How can I send an Image as ArrayBuffer to Java and save as Image File

Tags: javascript, java, filereader, arraybuffer

I use the function readAsArrayBuffer of FileReader to get the content of the selected image.

```
 reader.readAsArrayBuffer(file.target.files[i]);
```

After that, i want to send the ArrayBuffer to my Java Server

```
    reader.onload = function(fileData) 
    {
        uploadPhoto.fileData = fileData.target.result;

        funcupload([{name:'fileData',value:uploadPhoto.fileData}]);
    }
```

The Question is now, how can I convert the [object ArrayBuffer] in Java to an Image File?

I think its very simple, but I can't find a solution

Comment: why do you need to read the file with filereader at all? its already a File container, which you can just attach to the body of your request. this doesn't make any sense.

Comment: @r3wt  And how should I get the Data of the file.target.files[i] on the Java Serverside?

Comment: maybe do a tutorial on file uploads in Java (Springboot or whatever you use). As is, we don't know what you are doing server side, and you also don't show the code for `funcupload`, so its not possible for us to even help you, as you haven't provided sufficient information

Comment: @r3wt Thanks for your answer and sorry for not providing enough information
I have send a base64 String to the server and saved it as an Image, that worked, but took a lot of time.
Then I read that it is faster to send the ArrayBuffer to the Server an create the image
But i dont know how to get the ArrayBuffer Content and save it as an Image on Java Side